# IndexError in a recursive function inside a Class

Tags: python-3.x

I am having issues where I want the user to input a number that is 1-9. If they enter a number outside the range, I want them to get a message "Please enter a valid number" and to be able to enter another number. If they enter say "145" it will ask them to enter a valid number just like I want (yay!). Then when they enter, lets say "4", an IndexError: list out of range pops up. self.board is a list with 9 elements.

My thought is that python still trying to use the first number, but if I print the number before IndexError line, it shows the correct number, '4'. Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
    self.board=[
        " "," "," ",
        " "," "," ",
        " "," "," "
    ]
def turn(self, player):
   result=int(input("Choose your next move \n"))
   if result < 1 or result>9:
        print("Please enter a valid number (1-9)")
        self.turn(player)

   if self.board[result-1] == " ":
        self.board[result-1] = player
   else:
        print("This spot has already been chosen. Please choose another place for your next move")
        self.turn(player)
```

Comment: Can you edit with the full class? Is self.board initialised in the `__init__` function of your class? What is the length of `self.board` prior to assigning it to `player`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your method is recursive and execution continues after your recursion collapses. You have two if statements in a row. When the first one is true, it recurses but when that recursed call finishes it continues execution with the bad input. You need to make the second if statement an `elif` instead. That way after your recursed function call finishes nothing else is executed.

Try this instead:

```py
    self.board=[
        " "," "," ",
        " "," "," ",
        " "," "," "
    ]
def turn(self, player):
   result=int(input("Choose your next move \n"))
   if result < 1 or result>9:
        print("Please enter a valid number (1-9)")
        self.turn(player)

   elif self.board[result-1] == " ":
        self.board[result-1] = player
   else:
        print("This spot has already been chosen. Please choose another place for your next move")
        self.turn(player)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the explanation. That makes a lot of sense to me now.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it worked for you? :) I would appreciate it